# Displaying count of item in one table and all it's columns in another

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
For each pizza, display its count of rows in Stock
followed by all its columns in Product.
```

**Stock Table**

```
   s_inv - Text - foreign key to Product
   s_num
   s_in_stock
```

**Product Table**

```
 p_inv - Text - Primary Key
 p_name
 p_price
```

Comment: Set Default value to 0.

Comment: Which Sql database you are using???

Comment: Ok have you tried anything??? Please include your query...

Comment: okay I added one I have to the post, that displays all columns in Product for each pizza but Im confused on how I display it's count of rows in Stock also

Comment: You want data from both the table or only Products table??

Comment: data from both tables so the count of rows in stock table followed by all columns in Product table for each individual pizza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql-server:

```
select p.p_inv,
       p.p_name,
       p.p_price,
       s.s_num,
       s.s_in_stock,
       count(select * from product p,stock s where p.p_inv=s.s_inv) 
as rows_count 
from product p 
join stock s on p.p_inv=s.s_inv 
order by p.s_inv;
```

Comment: to count row number where there's a match use count() ;

Comment: for faster execution use join operation

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and try this.

```
select p.p_inv,p.p_namep.p_price,count(select * from stock where s.s_inv=p.p_inv) from product p, stock s;
```

Comment: that give's me all the records back in each table, I need the records in Product and just the number of rows the pizza has in Stock